# Why does my private Ethereum blockchain with PoA consensus keep returning to block number 1 after a few days of running and how can I prevent it?

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, private

I have set up a private Ethereum blockchain with Proof of Authority (PoA) consensus. I have configured the block time to 0, as I don't want to continuously generate empty blocks and occupy storage space. I have connected an API and a smart contract to my private blockchain. I want to create a new block only when a user sends a request to the smart contract. However, I'm facing two problems.

Firstly, when I leave the blockchain running for a couple of days, it returns to block number 1. Why does this happen? Secondly, the smart contract stops functioning, and I need to delete it and run "truffle migrate" again to make it work. Why is this happening? Second, the smart contract stops functioning, and I have to delete it and run "truffle migrate" again to make it work. Why does this happen?

Comment: This question does not have enough details to be answerable. Please read how to ask a good question tutorial first https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask